# WebGL Unity External StreamingAssets

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have to load some external files from a directory. I'm putting the files in the Assets / StreamingAssets folder. File format of files is otud. The project I'm using: https://slavi.gitbook.io/opentibiaunity/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.